# No POST route - nested resources causing confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get the following error when submitting my new restaurant form:
    No route matches [POST] "/restaurants"

And there is no [POST] path when I run rake routes. I get the following:

```
user_restaurants GET    /users/:user_id/restaurants(.:format)             restaurants#index
                         POST   /users/:user_id/restaurants(.:format)             restaurants#create
     new_user_restaurant GET    /users/:user_id/restaurants/new(.:format)         restaurants#new
         edit_restaurant GET    /restaurants/:id/edit(.:format)                   restaurants#edit
              restaurant GET    /restaurants/:id(.:format)                        restaurants#show
                         PATCH  /restaurants/:id(.:format)                        restaurants#update
                         PUT    /restaurants/:id(.:format)                        restaurants#update
                         DELETE /restaurants/:id(.:format)                        restaurants#destroy
```

My routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users
resources :users, :shallow => true do
  resources :restaurants do
    resources :reviews, except: [:index, :show] #create review paths
  end
end
```

My user.rb:

```
has_many :reviews
has_many :restaurants
```

My restaurant.rb:

```
has_many :reviews
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :user
```

My restaurants_controller.rb:

```
before_action :set_user
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :new, :edit, :update, 
:destroy]
before_action :check_if_owner?, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

def new
  @restaurant = Restaurant.new(user: @user) #create a new restaurant
end

def create
  @restaurant = current_user.restaurants.build(restaurant_params)
  @restaurant.user = @user
  @restaurant.save
  redirect_to @restaurant
end

private
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end  

  def restaurant_params
    params.require(:restaurant).permit(:name, :description, :category_id,
    :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zipcode, :phone, :email, :image, 
    :user_id)
  end
```

My restaurants/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @restaurant do |f| %>
```

Is there a better way to tie a restaurant to a user in order to allow a restaurant owner to edit their page? If not, how would I go about fixing the error?

```
<%= link_to "Create a Restaurant", 
new_user_restaurant_path(current_user.id), class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary"%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this in your form:

`<%= form_for [@user, @restaurant] do |f| %>`

You can read about it here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#relying-on-record-identification

Comment: That fixed the routing error, now I am getting "Couldn't find User with 'id'=" when running set_user. I updated the post with the link to the create restaurant page.

Comment: This error is raising on #create action right? It is because you should not execute it there, doesn't make sense since you're doing `current_user.restaurants.build(restaurant_params)`. You should change your callback to this `before_action :set_user, except: :create` and in your create action remove `@restaurant.user = @user`

Comment: Thanks for the help! This got it working. I also had to change the code in set_user to @user = current_user.

Comment: Honestly I think you should remove the set_user method completely, you don't need it at all. You can try as an extra, it will be a better code ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're misusing nesting. When nesting routes you should only ever nest one level deep:

```
resources :restaurants, shallow: true do
  resources :reviews
end

resources :users do
  # ...
end
```

And nesting should be used for context - not authentication/authorization.

And while you could nest the create action for `restaurants` under users `POST /users/:user_id/restaurants` only makes sense if you are creating a restaurant for other users.

```
class RestaurantsController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :new, :edit, :update, 
:destroy]
  before_action :check_if_owner?, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # POST /restaurants
  def create
    @restaurant = current_user.restaurants.new(restaurant_params)

    # ...
  end
end
```

This reduces the level of complexity considerably. If you want to create nested routes to show the users restaurants or reviews a very powerful pattern is to use modules:

```
resources :reviews, except: [:new, :create]

resources :users do
  resources :reviews, only: [:index], module: :users
end
```

---

```
# app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  # GET /reviews
  def index
    @reviews = Review.all
  end
end

# app/controllers/users/reviews_controller.rb
class Users::ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /users/:user_id/reviews
  def index
    @user = User.includes(:reviews).find(params[:user_id])
    @reviews = @user.reviews
  end
end
```

This lets us use different controllers depending on the context. A users reviews is a very different resource than all the reviews.

When it comes to creating reviews for a restaurant you will want to use nesting as the path provides vital context.

```
resources :restaurants do
  resources :reviews, only: [:new, :create, :index], module: :users
end


# app/controllers/restaurants/reviews_controller.rb
class Restaurants::ReviewsController

  # GET /restaurants/:restaurant_id/reviews/new
  def new
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:Restaurant_id])
    @review = @restaurant.review.new
  end

  # POST /restaurants/:restaurant_id/reviews
  def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:Restaurant_id])
    @review = @restaurant.review.new(review_params) do |r|
      r.user = current_user
    end
    # ...
  end

  # GET /restaurants/:restaurant_id/reviews
  def index
    @restaurant = Restaurant.includes(:reviews).find(params[:Restaurant_id])
    @reviews = @restaurant.reviews
  end
end
```

---

```
# app/views/reviews/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(resource) do %>
  # ...
<% end %>

# app/views/restaurants/reviews/new.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'reviews/form', resource: [@review.restaurant, @review] %>

 # app/views/reviews/edit.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'reviews/form', resource: @review %>
```

Comment: Awesome response, thanks! This clears up a lot for me; I had no idea you could do so much without nesting. Really appreciate it.